# How can we remove the default blank row which appears at end of mx:Datagrid?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using an mx:DataGrid with a dataProvider to display Rows. I have checked the no of rows in my array ( which is 8 ) and the no of rows in the dataGrid. They both match, however I always get an extra blank row at the end of my data grid. How can I remove this row?

Regards
Aparna

Answer (score 1):

try this :
[How can I make datagrid height is equal to data content in Adobe Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271150/how-can-i-make-datagrid-height-is-equal-to-data-content-in-adobe-flex)
an example based on the answer I found there:

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>   <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
> <mx:DataGrid x="31" y="157" id="dg" rowCount="{dg.dataProvider.length}">
>  <mx:dataProvider>
>     <mx:ArrayCollection>
>         <mx:Object name="name1" date="25/11/2010" />
>         <mx:Object name="name2" date="24/11/2010" />
>         <mx:Object name="name3" date="23/11/2010" />
>         </mx:ArrayCollection>
>         </mx:dataProvider>
> </mx:DataGrid>
> </mx:Application>
> ```

One more thing ,dont specify the height of the grid explicitly in the mx:DataGrid tag.

Comment: I have tried  this, does not work. Still get a blank row at end

Answer (score 0):

Keep changing the size of your data grid in the design view so that it must be able to accomodate only fixed number of rows. Keep scroll policy false.

Comment: I cannot keep scroll policy false as I could have variable no of rows.

Answer (score 0):

The new spark DataGrid control  appears to solve this problem.